# How will you handle versioning if two different json (key) structure point to same pojo?

Tags: json, jackson

For example,
I have a POJO like this

```
class Sample
{
    private String name;
}
```

Second POJO

```
class Sample
{
    private Field field;
}
```

where the Field POJO contains

```
class Field 
{
    private String name;
    private int id;
}
```

I want the name field to support in both versions. Say, for version v2 I want the first POJO to support and for version v2.1 I want the second POJO to support. How to handle this with version-specific change?

Comment: Where do you want to fetch the version number from? Is it part of the input json itself or stored in some external field?

Comment: How rest api versioning can be done in such a way that it should not affect the business logic using jackson annotation? The business logic should be according to the current version.For example if a user hits /v2/read in the request uri it should point to the Sample class with "name" field as mentioned above and moves to business logic..if a user hits /v2.1/read it should point to Sample Class with "field" POJO.. How to hold the version control in json structure and deserialize it according to the business logic?